# Regular expression "OR" statement

Tags: php, regex

Is there any way to make the following code shorter using some kind of "OR" statement in regular expression?
I've tried using "|" but can figure out what's the correct way to use it.

```
$message = preg_replace('#<div class="gmail_signature">(.*?)</div>#is', '', $message); // Remove Gmail signature
$message = preg_replace('#<div class="gmail_extra">(.*?)</div>#is', '', $message); // Remove Gmail extra
$message = preg_replace('#<div class="gmail_quote">(.*?)</div>#is', '', $message); // Remove Gmail quoted message
```

Comment: How about reading the manual first? `pattern: It can be either a string or an array with strings.`

Comment: OR use a proper HTML parser.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, will become something like this:

```
$message = preg_replace('#<div class="gmail_(signature|extra|quote)">(.*?)</div>#is', '', $message); // Remove Gmail signature
```

Comment: It will be better if you also suggest to use `?:` to ignore the first group capture.